# using ViewPager in API 8-10 in android

Tags: android, api, android-viewpager

i want to use [this sample](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) from Androidhive for using ViewPager. but i can't use it in API 8 till 10. how can i change this sample for this case? please help me.

```
public class MyAdapter  extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


public MyAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}

public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            return new One();

        case 1:
            return new Two();


    }
    return null;

}
```

}

and this is One.java :
and Two .java is the same.

```
public class One extends Fragment {
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater
        , ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one, container, false);

    // BTN
    assert rootView != null;
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.one_soundBTN)
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // play sound
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.one);
                    mediaPlayer.start();

                    //show image
                    rootView.findViewById(R.id.one_image).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });


    return rootView;
}
```

}

Comment: what is the problem? where you get an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActionBar tabs are deprecated check google's project [here](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/project.html) to help you implement tabs with viewpager

Comment: thanks, but i set up my app's context in FragmentPagerAdapter.i must use this adapter. is there any more solution that you can give  me?

Comment: @user3671748 can you please put the code of your adapter so i can tell you?

Comment: thanks, i post Adapter and Fragment classes.

Comment: and what do you want to do ?

Comment: I want to run this code and also that toturial in API 6 to 10, the min sdk in this toturial is 11.how can I do this?